# Pretty-printing not working in VS Code for C++ debugging using GDB

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, pretty-print

I am trying to use pretty-printing for debugging C++ in VS code under a Debian configuration.

Right now vectors are displayed like that : [Vector display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/955sZ.png)

My `launch.json` file is :

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Lancer",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/build/examples/005_friction/mode_III_slip_weakening",
            "args": ["dumps", "100", "100"],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/build/examples/005_friction/",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ] 
        }
    ],
}
```

I have also tried to add in `configurations`

```
"gdb": {
          "prettyPrinting": true}
```

In that case, I have an error "Property gdb is not allowed". But I have gdb installed on my computer. I also have the "C/C++" extension installed in VS code.

At last, I tried to type `-exec -enable-pretty-printing` in the Debug console without further success.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue in VSCode (debian env). running `apt-get install gdb` do the trick for me. it will install some additional packages and after restarting VSCode the issue was resolved.